# seamlessly connect angled edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, node-connections, edge

I try to draw a very thick edge between two specific anchors of nodes. In reality, they target segments of multipart nodes, but I kept it simple for this example.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node[below right=1 and 2 of A] (B) {B};
  \draw[line width=7] (A.east) to (B.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in ugly gaps where the edge meets the node.

[image: gaps]

I am aware that I could put the edge in a scope `on background layer` using the `backgrounds` TikZ library. This would get rid of the part overlapping into the nodes. But it would not fix the gaps where the edge is too short to reach the node border.

- Setting `line cap=rect` is not enough to close it when the edge has a rather steep angle.
- Elongating the edge could make it pop out the other side of the node.

How can I reach a seamless connection between edge and node, looking somewhat like the following picture?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would be inclined to simply fill a path rather than drawing a line:

```
  \fill (A.east) +(0,3.5pt) -- ([yshift=3.5pt]B.west) -- +(0,-7pt) -- ([yshift=-3.5pt]A.east) -- cycle;
```

[image: filled path faking line]

This leaves an annoying, albeit slight, gap visible here between the 'line' and the border of node A. To avoid this, draw the filled area, also:

```
\filldraw (A.east) +(0,3.5pt) -- ([yshift=3.5pt]B.west) -- +(0,-7pt) -- ([yshift=-3.5pt]A.east) -- cycle;
```

[image: fill-draw faking line]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [every node/.style={draw}]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node [below right=1 and 2 of A] (B) {B};
  \filldraw (A.east) +(0,3.5pt) -- ([yshift=3.5pt]B.west) -- +(0,-7pt) -- ([yshift=-3.5pt]A.east) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

For convenience, you could define a `pic` to handle some of this automatically. The following defines 2 such: `lr connection` for left-to-right (ish) connections and `tb connection` for up-down (ish) connections. Obviously, you'd have to do a bit more work to enable options for 'mixed' modes e.g. from a `.north` anchor to an `.east` one. But the same idea could be used - only the `from` and `to` would be crucially different in this case.

The basic syntax is as follows:

```
\pic [lr connect={from=<point to connect from>, to=<point to connect to>, line width=<connector width>}, <other tikz options>] {lr connection};
```

for left-right connections and

```
\pic [tb connect={from=<point to connect from>, to=<point to connect to>, line width=<connector width>}, <other tikz options>] {tb connection};
```

for top-bottom connections.

Here's an extremely ugly illustration of the possible output:

[image: ugly demo]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [every node/.style={draw}]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node [below right=1 and 2 of A] (B) {B};
  \pic [lr connect={from=A.east, to=B.west, line width=7pt}] {lr connection};
  \pic [lr connect={from=B.east, to={4,0}}] {lr connection};
  \node (C) at (6,-1) {C};
  \pic [lr connect={from={4,0}, to=C.west}, blue] {lr connection};
  \pic [lr connect={from=C.west, to=B.east, line width=5pt}, green] {lr connection};
  \node (D) [below left=of B -| C] {D};
  \node (E) [below left=of B] {E};
  \pic [tb connect={from=C.south, to=D.north, line width=7pt}, red] {tb connection};
  \pic [tb connect={from=E.north, to=A.south, line width=6pt}, orange] {tb connection};
  \pic [lr connect={from=D.west, to=E.east, line width=10pt}, magenta] {lr connection};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

## EDIT 2

You can define commands `\lrconnect[<optional arguments for tikz>]{<connection options>}` and `\tbconnect[<tikz options>]{<connection options>}` for further convenience.

Then the same ugly output can be specified as

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [every node/.style={draw}]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node [below right=1 and 2 of A] (B) {B};
  \lrconnect{from=A.east, to=B.west, line width=7pt};
  \lrconnect{from=B.east, to={4,0}};
  \node (C) at (6,-1) {C};
  \lrconnect[blue]{from={4,0}, to=C.west};
  \lrconnect[green]{from=C.west, to=B.east, line width=5pt};
  \node (D) [below left=of B -| C] {D};
  \node (E) [below left=of B] {E};
  \tbconnect[red]{from=C.south, to=D.north, line width=7pt};
  \tbconnect[orange]{from=E.north, to=A.south, line width=6pt};
  \lrconnect[magenta]{from=D.west, to=E.east, line width=10pt};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, this also offers some more interesting possibilities. For example:

[image: fancier stuff]

can be produced using something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    every node/.style={fill=blue!75, text=white, font=\bfseries},
    tb connect={line width=7pt},
    lr connect={line width=7pt},
    draw=blue!25,
  ]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node [below right=1 and 2 of A] (B) {B};
  \node (C) at (6,-1) {C};
  \node (D) [below left=of B -| C] {D};
  \node (E) [below left=of B] {E};
  \foreach \i/\j in {A.east/B.west,C.west/B.east,D.west/E.east}
  {
    \lrconnect[left color=blue, right color=green]{from=\i,to=\j};
    \foreach \k in {.9,.8,...,.1}
    \lrconnect[fill=white, fill opacity=.75-.75*\k, draw=none]{from=\i,to=\j,line width=\k*7pt};
  }
  \foreach \i/\j in {C.south/D.north,E.north/A.south}
  {
    \tbconnect[left color=blue, right color=magenta]{from=\i,to=\j};
    \foreach \k in {.9,.8,...,.1}
    \tbconnect[fill=white, fill opacity=.75-.75*\k, draw=none]{from=\i,to=\j,line width=\k*7pt};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

## Complete code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
  lr connection/.pic={
    \filldraw [pic actions] (\myconnectfrom) +(0,.5*\myconnectwidth) -- ([yshift=.5*\myconnectwidth]\myconnectto) -- +(0,-\myconnectwidth) -- ([yshift=-.5*\myconnectwidth]\myconnectfrom) -- cycle;
  },
  lr connect/.code={
    \tikzset{
      lr connections/.cd,
      #1
    },
  },
  lr connections/.cd,
  from/.store in=\myconnectfrom,
  to/.store in=\myconnectto,
  line width/.store in=\myconnectwidth,
  from={0,0},
  to={0,0},
  line width=.4pt,
  /tikz/.cd,
  tb connection/.pic={
    \filldraw [pic actions] (\myconnectfrom) +(.5*\myconnectwidth,0) -- ([xshift=.5*\myconnectwidth]\myconnectto) -- +(-\myconnectwidth,0) -- ([xshift=-.5*\myconnectwidth]\myconnectfrom) -- cycle;
  },
  tb connect/.code={
    \tikzset{
      tb connections/.cd,
      #1
    },
  },
  tb connections/.cd,
  from/.store in=\myconnectfrom,
  to/.store in=\myconnectto,
  line width/.store in=\myconnectwidth,
  from={0,0},
  to={0,0},
  line width=.4pt,
}
\newcommand*\lrconnect[2][]{%
   \pic [lr connect={#2}, #1] {lr connection}}
\newcommand*\tbconnect[2][]{%
   \pic [tb connect={#2}, #1] {tb connection}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [every node/.style={draw}]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node [below right=1 and 2 of A] (B) {B};
  \pic [lr connect={from=A.east, to=B.west, line width=7pt}] {lr connection};
  \pic [lr connect={from=B.east, to={4,0}}] {lr connection};
  \node (C) at (6,-1) {C};
  \pic [lr connect={from={4,0}, to=C.west}, blue] {lr connection};
  \pic [lr connect={from=C.west, to=B.east, line width=5pt}, green] {lr connection};
  \node (D) [below left=of B -| C] {D};
  \node (E) [below left=of B] {E};
  \pic [tb connect={from=C.south, to=D.north, line width=7pt}, red] {tb connection};
  \pic [tb connect={from=E.north, to=A.south, line width=6pt}, orange] {tb connection};
  \pic [lr connect={from=D.west, to=E.east, line width=10pt}, magenta] {lr connection};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [every node/.style={draw}]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node [below right=1 and 2 of A] (B) {B};
  \lrconnect{from=A.east, to=B.west, line width=7pt};
  \lrconnect{from=B.east, to={4,0}};
  \node (C) at (6,-1) {C};
  \lrconnect[blue]{from={4,0}, to=C.west};
  \lrconnect[green]{from=C.west, to=B.east, line width=5pt};
  \node (D) [below left=of B -| C] {D};
  \node (E) [below left=of B] {E};
  \tbconnect[red]{from=C.south, to=D.north, line width=7pt};
  \tbconnect[orange]{from=E.north, to=A.south, line width=6pt};
  \lrconnect[magenta]{from=D.west, to=E.east, line width=10pt};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    every node/.style={fill=blue!75, text=white, font=\bfseries},
    tb connect={line width=7pt},
    lr connect={line width=7pt},
    draw=blue!25,
  ]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node [below right=1 and 2 of A] (B) {B};
  \node (C) at (6,-1) {C};
  \node (D) [below left=of B -| C] {D};
  \node (E) [below left=of B] {E};
  \foreach \i/\j in {A.east/B.west,C.west/B.east,D.west/E.east}
  {
    \lrconnect[left color=blue, right color=green]{from=\i,to=\j};
    \foreach \k in {.9,.8,...,.1}
    \lrconnect[fill=white, fill opacity=.75-.75*\k, draw=none]{from=\i,to=\j,line width=\k*7pt};
  }
  \foreach \i/\j in {C.south/D.north,E.north/A.south}
  {
    \tbconnect[left color=blue, right color=magenta]{from=\i,to=\j};
    \foreach \k in {.9,.8,...,.1}
    \tbconnect[fill=white, fill opacity=.75-.75*\k, draw=none]{from=\i,to=\j,line width=\k*7pt};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The example I presented here is a simplified version. My real use case actually defines `outer sep=0` globally because all the shapes are `fill`ed but not `draw`n, so I could even your first solution is very applicable for me.

Comment: @XZS Please see edit. I'm not sure how useful this is, but I was procrastinating.

Comment: This could be quite useful for the picture I am striving for. Thank you.

Comment: I added command versions as I think these are easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

Is there request that line should be between `(A.east)` and `B.west`? See if `\draw[...]  (A.center) -- (B.center)` on background layer is acceptable for you:

[image]

For above picture you need TikZ library `backgrounds` and define fill for nodes:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               preview
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,fill=white}]
      \node (A) {A};
      \node[below right=1 and 2 of A] (B) {B};
    \scoped[on background layer]
\path   let \p1 = (A.center),
            \p2 = (B.center),
            \n1 = {veclen(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)} in
    (A.east) to node[sloped, fill=black,
                     minimum width=\n1, 
                     minimum height=3pt] {} 
    (B.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

**Edit:** As you note in comment (and I before overlooked in your question) you will replace the line with some (multi part) node. Therefore I now replace a previous line with empty node with width of 5pt and `fill=black` by which I mimic previous line. You can replace this node with your real one ... however, if the node will has higher minimum height, their ends  will not be chopped with nodes A and B ... .

You can see, that I calculated minimum width of node as distance between centers of nodes A and B. If this distance will be adequate for your real node. It can be dependent from node height.

Is this what you looking for?

**Edit (2):**
I will try once again to guess, what is the problem ... so another solution, which consider multi-part nodes (determined by split rectangle) and connecting different parts by (very thick?) lines:

[image]

Code for this solution is relatively simple:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               preview
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}

     \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={draw,fill=white},
    shorten <>/.style={shorten >=#1, shorten <=#1}]
  \node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3] (A) 
        {A1\nodepart{two}A2\nodepart{three}A3};
  \node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
        below right=1 and 2 of A] (B) 
        {B1\nodepart{two}B2\nodepart{three}B3};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[line width=4pt,red!50,
      shorten <>=-4pt]   (A.one east) -- (B.three west);
\draw[line width=4pt,teal!50,
      shorten <>=-4pt]   (A.two east) -- (B.one west);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
     \end{document}
```

Extension of lines I select equal to line width, which is adequate for line slope above 45 degree ... I t can be simple calculated with basic geometry :-)

**Note:**  This solution is not appropriate for lines with arrows on the end, they will be partly covered by nodes. In this case a solution can be used decorated path with arrow somewhere on line between its ends.

Comment: Yes, the lines have to end at specific anchors. As written in the question, they should be able to point at segments of multipart nodes.

Comment: @XZS, ok, I correct my answer, however, it is not as simple as befor :-)

Comment: I don't think the *line* is being replaced by a multi-part node. Isn't the idea that the *nodes* (A and B) are, in fact, parts of multi-part nodes? Maybe I've misunderstood the question or your answer, but that's how I understood it....

Comment: @cfr is right, the nodes A and B are to be replaced by more complex constructs. The computation of minimum width is valuable nonetheless.

Comment: @XZS, now I'm confused. It seems now, that my first version of mine answer was correct .. if Now I understand your question correctly, in real case you will have to (or more) multi-part nodes and you like to their connect different parts? With lines with 7pt width? P

Comment: @Zarko your first answer did not take into account that the edge has to go from one specific anchor to the other and cannot just go from the center of the first node to the center of the second node. Your answer is much more useful as it is now.

Comment: @XZS, I assume, that I now know, what you looking for, so I will add my a solution of my last guessing ...

Comment: @Zarko That is the one I need. The minimum needed `shorten` value could indeed be automatically computed from the line width and angle.

Comment: @XZS, glad to hear this! Can I expect, that you will accept ma answer :_)   In the case of arrow on one end  of a line just don't use shorten for this end ...